# How to search Penn TreeBank for arbitrary patterns?

Tags: syntax-trees, nltk

What is a general way to parse the trees in the Penn TreeBank for arbitrary patterns, e.g. perhaps I want all trees which have a plural subject and whose sister VP has a modal verb daughter.

Another example would be finding all trees which have a VP headed by some verb and which have a daughter PP headed by *to*.  This isn't even a subtree match--it's only matching an incomplete part of the tree.

This doesn't seem very easy, because the trees are not regular structures but are presumably context-free (or even context-sensitive).

I thought about converting the trees to strings, but regex obviously doesn't not work for this.  Regex is useful for finding whole (sub)trees, but I wish to find patterns among different phrases/nodes in the tree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is tagged for NLTK, but if you're free to switch, Stanford NLP has a product called [Tregex](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tregex.shtml) which does exactly this kind of tree search.

You might also be able to shell out to the Tregex binary, which has a fairly useful CLI as well. See documentation on [TregexPattern#main](http://web.mit.edu/course/6/6.863/OldFiles/tools/tregex/javadoc/edu/stanford/nlp/trees/tregex/TregexPattern.html#main(java.lang.String[])) for more.

You can find some introductory documentation [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/manning/courses/ling289/Tregex.html).

(Disclaimer: I work in the Stanford NLP Group and have contributed to the Tregex project.)

Comment: My preference is to stick with Python, unless Stanford NLP also has a Python version?

Comment: There is a Python bridge, though it doesn't support Tregex as far as I know. You could shell out to the Tregex binary; see TregexPattern#main for info: http://web.mit.edu/course/6/6.863/OldFiles/tools/tregex/javadoc/edu/stanford/nlp/trees/tregex/TregexPattern.html#main(java.lang.String[])

Answer (score 3):

There are quite a few tools which can do this.

For example:
Tregex mentioned by Jon Gauthier.

I know a few others:

- PML-TQ https://ufal.mff.cuni.cz/pmltq/
- Tundra https://weblicht.sfs.uni-tuebingen.de/tundra-beta
- Iness search

Among them, I know Tundra best since I used to work in the group who created it.
Tundra has a very nice UI based on bootstrap, as well as a cool tree visualizer based on D3.
It uses the well-known tiger search language and supports searching both constituency trees and dependency trees.
Thanks to the highly efficient indexing scheme it employs, Tundra can handle large-scale Treebanks, such as automatically parsed Wikipedia.